# EF Core DI - Two writes fail

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm having an issue where two methods may write to a database at the same time in my WPF app, and this fails. I have a process that's doing a large update that takes maybe 5 seconds. It's writing a load of rows that are in a List<>.

While it's writing, an event on a timer triggers, which writes an update to a different table.

I think it's because my app uses one DB Context. At startup, I have the usual DI code:

```
services.AddDbContext<FlightDataContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer("Data Source = ...."));
```

And then I use DI in my data access class to do the DB activities.

Should I be using a different instance of the context, somehow?

My data access class has a constructor, and uses DI at that point:

private readonly MyContext dataContext;

```
public FlightData(MyContext dataContext)
{
    this.dataContext= dataContext;
}
```

I think I'm going wrong here maybe, but not sure how to get around the issue of the same context performing two write operations at the same time.

Comment: You can use `IServiceProvide.CreateScope()` and then use the scoped context in your timers `Tick` method. So every tick will have its own context.

Comment: Does your connection string allow for multiple active results sets?

Comment: From the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration) : DbContext is not thread-safe. Do not share contexts between threads. Make sure to await all async calls before continuing to use the context instance.

Comment: Not sure if my Connection string allows for multiple connections. How do I validate that? Would I use create scooped on my tick method only?

Comment: By the way, how does the error look like?